# Removing DCC and its by-product from Steglich Esterfication

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis, alcohols, esters

In my small research, I want to synthesize 3 **alkyl gallates** (ethyl gallate, butyl gallate, and hexyl gallate), and here's my overall reaction using **Steglich esterification**):

[image: Steglich esterification; alkyl gallate]

However, from reading some literature, it's mentioned that using DCC in Steglich esterification has drawbacks; it produces a by-product (DCU) and can prove difficult to remove remaining trace amounts.

**My questions:**

1. Are there any effective methods to remove the DCC by-product and the remaining trace amounts? If there are, could you tell me in detail about the methods?
2. Otherwise, could you suggest me a different way/reaction to synthesize alkyl gallate (using easily available chemicals)

**Important Note:**

I'm aware that I could use DIC or EDC to prevent this problem, but I don't have DIC or EDC, and I'm trying to avoid purchasing them because they're quite expensive in my country.

Comment: According to this discussion thread https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_remove_DCU_dicyclohexyl_urea_by_product_formed_during_estrification_reaction_via_DCC_DMAP_with_carboxylic_acids   dissolve your product mixture in the minimum amount of cold MeCN and filter to remove DCU. Do this a couple of times.

Comment: You'd really use THF at 0C? Why not DCM at RT? If you pick right solvent DCU simply precipitates out. Also higher temp. makes reaction faster and lowers risk of oxidation - you'd need to keep O2 off.

Comment: Ah, you make a valid point. I chose THF as the solvent and set the temperature to 0°C based on the method outlined in this publication (http://dx.doi.org/10.13005/ojc/340207). I think I've become too reliant on this method.

But, could you elaborate on the risk of oxidation? Like, is gallic acid easy to oxidize in RT or what?

Comment: Higher temp. means faster reaction. At RT it still could take a week, but for some reason your procedure is faster. Looks like gallic acid is insoluble in DCM, though.